# go imported and not used: as, undefined

Tags: go

I renamed file as File,and renamed  moetemplate as htmlparts
then go build

```
./router.go:8: imported and not used: "github.com/golangframework/File" as file
./router.go:11: imported and not used: "github.com/golangframework/htmlparts" as moetemplate
./router.go:21: undefined: File in File.ReadAllBytes
./router.go:61: undefined: htmlparts in htmlparts.LoadPartFile
./router.go:62: undefined: File in File.ReadAllText
./router.go:65: undefined: htmlparts in htmlparts.Render
```

my import is this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/golangframework/File"
    "github.com/golangframework/JSON"
    "github.com/golangframework/Object"
    "github.com/golangframework/htmlparts"
    "github.com/golangframework/httpmongo"
    "github.com/golangframework/moeregexp"
)
```

and i also cleaned goroot pkg,updated src
why build error?

Comment: Your error indicates that your import statement is actually aliasing the packages and then you're not referring to those aliases. ie yo uhave `import moetemplat "github.com/golangframework/htmlparts"`. With `File` you have the alias `file` which is why you get those other errors because your code continues to reference `File` when now the package is referred to as `file` in that scope.

Comment: oh,,,sorry,I check the goroot scr,and find the old moetemplate.go and file.go still exist so I delete those,and go get from github,than OK

Answer (score 2):

Note the different capitalization of `file` and `File`. Since you talk about renaming file, I'm assuming that your code really is like

```
package main

import (
    file "github.com/golangframework/File"
)

func main() {
    File.ReadAllBytes("foo")
}
```

Either don't rename your `File` module (remove the `file` in the import) or refer to it as `file` instead of `File`.